# How to stretch the background color to be width of the parent container after applying padding to it-CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix a padding issue where I apply padding to he parent container, like this:
css:

```
   .main {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #b0bfc6;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px
}

.m1 {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top:20px;
}

.m2 {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

my html:

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="m1">some content
 </div>
 <div class="m2">some content

 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I apply padding to the "main" class `div` the selection background get padded as well as shown in fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/btjpk5f0/7/

Is there a way where I could apply padding to the parent container, but still be able to stretch the selected background color to be the full width of the container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative margin could help.

```
.main > div {
  margin-left:-20px;
  margin-right:-20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btjpk5f0/5/

[EDIT:]
You cannot stretch the background without enlarging the div, but you may add the same padding to inner elements:

```
.main > div {
  margin-left:-20px;
  margin-right:-20px;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
}
```

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/btjpk5f0/11/

Comment: sorry for the confusion from my second fiddle, I didnt mean the text to move to the left as well... I want the text to be padded 20px, but just the bg color to be strecth full-width

Comment: Simply add the same padding to inner elements, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way where I could apply padding to the parent container,
>   but still be able to stretch the selected background color to be the
>   full width of the container?

No, not really.

Do you have to apply padding to the parent container?  You could apply the padding to the child divs, like so:

```
.main {
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #b0bfc6;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0 /* No padding here*/
}

.m1 {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top:20px;
  padding:0 20px /* left/right padding here */;
}

.m2 {
  color: #000;
  margin-top:20px;
  padding:20px /* apply padding here instead of on the parent */;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/er9ubxo8/1/

That gives you the desired layout ....

Comment: the reason I added it to the parent, coz there are few other child components below the selection list and these childs are dynamic, so instead of adding padding to every child, I thought adding padding to parent would be feasible

Comment: I understand, but you could easily target "every child", using the > * selector.